# Remove subdomain from url

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

So i have this kind of code, which returns the domain name, but i cant figure out how to remove subdomain, can anyone help ?

```
$link='http://www.lol.wwwyoursitewww.com/aaaaa/ggghd/site.php?sadf=asg';
preg_match('/^http\:\/\/www.(.*?)\/.*/i', $link, $link_domain);
echo $link_domain[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the built-in parse_url to do as much as possible, which will just leave you with the domain name to sort out. I was a little unclear on the requirements. What is the expected output? - just wwwyoursitewww.com? or http://wwwyoursitewww.com/aaaaa/ggghd/site.php?sadf=asg

```
$link='http://www.lol.wwwyoursitewww.com/aaaaa/ggghd/site.php?sadf=asg';

$url = parse_url($link);

if (preg_match("/(www.*?)\.(.*)/", $url['host'], $m)) {
  $url['host'] = $m[2];
}

$rebuild = $url['scheme'] . '://' . $url['host'] . $url['path'] . '?' . $url['query'];

echo "$rebuild\n";
```

Comment: Please DO NOT embed variables in the string. It is prone to problems with n00bs who see this and start to use single quotes. There have been some q's with that exact problem.

Comment: @ColeJohnson Hmm ok, I'll bow to your better judgement on that. Example updated.

Comment: Also. For `$m[2]`, should you use `$m[sizeof($m) - 1]`? Or am I wrong? I don't know REGEX that well.

Comment: @cole: no need... it will only execute if a match is found and if that match is found there will always be `$m[2]`

Comment: `sub2.sub.foo.co.uk` vs `sub2.sub.xx.se`, gl hf removing all subdomains.

Comment: This won't work for the above comment reason. You need a list of all the tld and then remove everything from . to left to the beginning.

Comment: My point was that you could use url_parse() for the URL parsing, thus simplifying the problem. The host parsing part is a much more difficult problem! If I have any more downvotes I'll simply delete this answer.

Comment: to add to this answer, if you modify the regex to the following

    `/(.*?)\.(.*)/`

it will look for all subdomains, not just www

Answer (score 0):

```
$link='http://www.lol.wwwyoursitewww.com/aaaaa/ggghd/site.php?sadf=asg';
preg_match('!www((\.(\w)+))+!', $link, $match);
$link_arr=(explode(".", $match[0]));
echo $link_domain = $link_arr[count($link_arr)-1];
```

Output: `com`

Answer (score 0):

Get `host` without subdomain. Work with `www`

```
/**
   * Get Host without subdomain
   * @param $host
   * @return string
   */
  public static function giveHost($host): string
  {
    $newHost    = $host;
    $host_array = explode('.', $host);
    $countDot   = count($host_array);
    if ($countDot > 2){
      $newHost = $host_array[$countDot-2].'.'.$host_array[$countDot-1];
      if (preg_match('/www/', $host)){
        $newHost = 'www.'.$newHost;
      }
    }
    return $newHost;
  }
```